# How can i output to console my request's body

Tags: java, http, httpclient

Can't output to console "POST" requests body

```
HttpClient client= HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost request=new HttpPost("https://reqres.in/api/register");
 List<NameValuePair> params= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","eve.holt@reqres.in"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","pistol"));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I want to see the body of requests(email, password).

I've tried
    System.out.println(request.getEntity())
but it's not exactly same
thx

Comment: It might help to know why you want to do this. Do you just want to debug, or, say, write every request to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache httpclient creates a model in the form of `HttpPost`, which isn't a raw request. When you `execute()`, this is internally transformed into a HTTP payload and processed, and you are presented with the response again as a modeled object.

You can log the requests and responses though using the Wire logger: `org.apache.http.wire`. More information here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html.

The raw data seems to be available in `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection`, but you'd have to override quite a few components of httpclient to get it out.